# Pandas does not read CSV as it write it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export

I created a dataframe, and i wanted to export it as a CSV. i used the
`df.to_csv()` method.

When i read my csv that i created it's not parsed well and i have some
values of columns mixed between each others.

I tried to change the encoding, as well as the delimiter, but it
doesn't solve my problem.

here is a sample of my dataframe before being exported as a CSV :

```
                                           societe  ...     cluster
    6                      ACTION AIR ENVIRONNEMENT  ...  aquavalley
    7                                    AD NUCLEIS  ...  aquavalley
    8                                        AD'OCC  ...  aquavalley
    9                                     ADEQUABIO  ...  aquavalley
    10                              ADICT SOLUTIONS  ...  aquavalley
```

then i use to export it :

```
csv_df.to_csv(r"path.csv", sep="\t")
```

and to read it :

```
pd.read_csv(r"path.csv", sep="\t", engine='python')
```

and i obtain something like that

```
    7                                    AD NUCLEIS  ...  aquavalley
    8                                        AD'OCC  ...        None
    215 Rue         34000 Mont...    contact@cc.com  ...        None         
    9                                     ADEQUABIO  ...  aquavalley
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data which raises the error ?

Comment: At least add comma, before engine='python'

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the argument `index` in `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv(r"path.csv", sep="\t", index=False)
```

Or a problem could be that your fields contain tabs, so in this case I would suggest you to change separator

Answer (score -1):

try reading it as `pd.read_csv("path.csv")`

Answer (score -1):

*Thank you for your fast answers. I solved my problem.*

I thought i got rid of carriage return '\r' and new line '\n' by using df.replace('\r',' ') but it didn't work(still don't know why), so they were still here when i thought they were not.

Instead i used :

```
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=[" "," "], regex=True)
```

and after getting rid of it, i don't have any problem.

Thanks again for your help.